# WP Taxonomy - Meta Key Name and Meta Key Value

Tags: wordpress, metadata, meta-tags

I was wondering if Wordpress Taxonomies have or can have Meta Key Name and Meta Key Values?

So if I have a taxonomy 'books' and a taxonomy term 'comics' for example.

Would the metadata key for the taxonomy be '_books' and value 'comics' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, taxonomies can have meta data (since 4.4.0). It works pretty much the same way as post or user meta works.
You have the following functions to work with term meta:

- [add_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/)
- [get_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/)
- [update_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/)
- [delete_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_term_meta/)

> So if I have a taxonomy 'books' and a taxonomy term 'comics' for example.
>   Would the metadata key for the taxonomy be '_books' and value 'comics' ?

No, since it works in the same way as post or user meta, both `meta_key` and `meta_value` would be what you set them to be

Comment: Thanks Igor .. would you by any chance know of an easy to follow tutorial on how to add a meta_key and meta_value to the taxonomy?

Comment: @JoeBloggs I don't know of any tbh but it's pretty straight forward. Let's say you have a term with ID 13, which for the sake of the simplicity is `old comics` and you would like to add meta to it, for example `years` for the range of years these comics were published in. So you could do `update_term_meta(13,'years','1989-1995');` to add it and then on the page of the term for example, you could get it using something like  `get_term_meta(get_queried_object()->term_id, 'years', true);`

Comment: Many thanks Igor, that does actually seem to be really straight forward.

Comment: So what does `1989-1995` in your example refer to? Let's say I have a taxonomy called `Books` (does taxonomy have ID?) and this taxonomy has 2 terms in it - `comics (term ID 20)` and `drama (term ID 21)` .. Now I now know that I can assign `meta_value` to both terms ID 20 and 21 with `update_term_meta(20,'comic_books');` and `update_term_meta(21,'drama_books');` (is this correct by the way?) ... by how do I assign `meta_key` to the actual taxonomy `books` ?

Comment: @JoeBloggs no, you got that wrong. I think you're misunderstanding whole concept of term meta. Maybe [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/how-to-use-term-meta-data-in-wordpress/) will be helpful to you.